# How to filter results based on keys in other object with Angular?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, filter, angular-ngselect

I have an object say it's called this.car and it looks like this and gets displayed on a page:

```
this.car = {
    id: 1,
    title: "F40",
    make: ferrari,
    color: red,
    category: fast
};
```

I then have an array of search results looking for cars, which return from an endpoint which might look like this:

```
let uri = `fast-cars/search?make=${make}&color=${color}&title=${title}`;
```

I might be on a page displaying information about the above car. if I search for cars via the searchable autocomplete drop-down I am using for search, I don't want the above car object to display in the returned list. But currently, the title is still showing in the options array.

if my results array looks like this:

```
this.results = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "F40",
      make: ferrari,
      color: red,
      category: fast
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: "911",
      make: porsche,
      color: black,
      category: fast
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: "Focus",
      make: ford,
      color: yellow,
      category: slow
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      title: "T-Series",
      make: Bentley,
      color: grey,
      category: fast
    }
];
```

I then want to filter the results against values in the first object, but my filter isn't working. i.e id: 1 should be removed from the drop-down.

I then use this method which is being called like this elsewhere on subscribing to results:

```
results => {
  if (results) {
    this.results = results;
    this.filterSearchResults(this.results, this.car);
  }
}
```

I'm not brilliant with using filters on multiple values, so have hit a block in terms of getting this to work. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @NicholasK - naturally with most things in this job, the filter needs to remove objects with a series of values to be truly unique, so it's not quite as simple as checking via id unfortunately. :)

Answer (score 1):

This will remove an object from the array if the car object has the same properties (i.e title, make and color) as an object already present in the array:

```
this.results.filter(
   e => e.title !== car.title && e.make !== car.make && e.color !== car.color
);
```

---

If you want to just check if the object already exists then you can use `some` which will return a *boolean* value indicating whether the element exists or not:

```
return this.results.some(
   e => e.title === car.title && e.make === car.make && e.color === car.color
);
```

Comment: I tried the first option you have added in here, thank you by the way. Appreciate the help. However, the results still return the same object when the autocomplete searches for that  object. In theory, it shouldn't appear.

Comment: Can you paste the `car` object that you are trying to filter out?

Comment: can we go into a chat as I'll need to show you the true object, my question is generalized to protect any information I'm working with. If that makes sense?

Comment: does chat even exist anymore?

Comment: Yeah it does. But I believe the answer will work for you provided the information you have given is the same as the problem you are currently facing.

Comment: basically, yes the principle is exactly the same. Needs to check several key values, if those match the current object, then that object needs to be removed. Sadly as I have it set, the object still returns. :(

Comment: Strange. This worked fine for me. Can you create a stackblitz to replicate the issue?

Comment: [This](https://stackblitz.com/edit/new-del) is the stackblitz I used to replicate your issue. Check the ngOnInit()..

Comment: Yes, I have it set in a similar way, I am querying and endpoint, so drawing up a mock service etc, would take a little time. It may be due to the search endpoint being fired on keyup, might be why this sin't working

Comment: Yeah. It's something else that is causing the issue. If the answer resolved the filtering part of your problem, upvote and/or accept!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your conditional logic, fixed below. You needed

```
(result["color"] === car["color"] &&
result["make"] === car["make"] &&
result["title"] === car["title"])
```

Not

```
result["color"] && result["make"] && result["title"] ===
car["color"] && car["make"] && car["title"]
```

```js
const car = {
    id: 1,
    title: "F40",
    make: 'ferrari',
    color: 'red',
    category: 'fast'
};

const results = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "F40",
      make: 'ferrari',
      color: 'red',
      category: 'fast'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: "911",
      make: 'porsche',
      color: 'black',
      category: 'fast'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: "Focus",
      make: 'ford',
      color: 'yellow',
      category: 'slow'
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      title: "T-Series",
      make: 'Bentley',
      color: 'grey',
      category: 'fast'
    }
];


          
console.log(results.filter(result => 
  (result["color"] === car["color"] &&
  result["make"] === car["make"] &&
  result["title"] === car["title"])
));
```

Comment: It jumped out at me so setting to !== sould remove the object from the array?

Comment: Yes it will or add a not check before the conditional like `!(...)`

Comment: Hi there, tried this option out also and the results still return the object that needs to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just want to remove the car that is already shown, so here you are with a simple filter method.Now results containe the proper cars.

```js
car = {
    id: 1,
    title: "F40",
    make: "ferrari",
    color: "red",
    category: "fast"
};
results = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "F40",
      make: "ferrari",
      color: "red",
      category: "fast"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: "911",
      make: "porsche",
      color: "black",
      category: "fast"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: "Focus",
      make: "ford",
      color: "yellow",
      category: "slow"
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      title: "T-Series",
      make: "Bentley",
      color: "grey",
      category: "fast"
    }
];
this.results= this.results.filter(listedcar=> listedcar.id !== this.car.id);
  console.log(this.results)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly you would like to filter out `this.car` in your `this.results` and display the remaining.

```
filterSearchResults() {
  var filteredList = this.results.filter(cars => cars.id !== this.car.id);
  // or have another global object like this.filteredCars
  console.log(filteredList);
};
```

Since `this.car` and `this.results` are global objects, you can use them directly in the function, no need to pass.